# .NET class inherits object class by default. How?

Tags: c#, .net, object

When we create a class Product

```
class Product
{
}
```

What I have learned from different blogs and books that `Object` class is the super/base/parent class of every class including user-defined classes.

How does this happens?

I assume it is taken care by .NET Framework? If its the case then I am curious to know how does this happens.

Comment: Why is that important? It's just a language implementation detail. So the type system just needs to include always  `System.Object`.

Comment: It is taken care by the compiler, cause you do not want to write each time the inheritance to object, like class `Product : Object {}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Supports all classes in the .NET Framework class hierarchy and provides low-level services to derived classes. This is the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the type hierarchy.

And why do you not 'see' this in the code:

> Languages typically do not require a class to declare inheritance from Object because the inheritance is implicit.

So in short the .Net type system does this implicit.

Comment: I guess that this quote doesn't answer the question since it basically repeats what OP has said. I think he wants the technical background behind this "implicit" inheritance.

Comment: Well as I see it, it does, because 'how' this happens is implicit.

Comment: I was actually looking for `And why do you not 'see' this in the code:`. I was not able to put it in right words.

Comment: @Ric.Net So you mean [CTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hf02550%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) does it behind the scenes?

Comment: I would surely do it in 2 mi. more :)

Comment: @Gun.IO Yep, this is what is at the background together with aershov's answer

Comment: What happens if Product inherits from some concrete class A? Does it still implicitly inherit from object, too? Because that would be multiple inheritance, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @BeniMurza I assume not. But it doesn't matter, because you can always cast to both `A` or `Object`.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, it's taken care by .Net Framework. Every Type inf is stored in a special table in memory when program is running. And type record contains link to a base class record. Every type that is not derived from any class contains a link to an object record.

Through this every type has methods, that are defined in a MethodTable (also in memory when .Net framework is running) as methods of object class. For example `GetHashCode` or `Equals`

Answer (score 2):

When you want to explore how things happen, you can always take it one step lower and look into the emitted metadata and IL code generated for each method.

For example, this is a `Person` class with one property, `Name`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When we look at the emitted IL we see ([using ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)) :

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit ConsoleApplication2.Person
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
   // Property declaration removed for brevity
}
```

The compiler add the `extends [mscorlib]System.Object`, where `mscorlib` is the declared assembly, `System` is the namespace and `Object` is the declared type.